# python/httpx/asyncio: httpx.RemoteProtocolError: Server disconnected without sending a response

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio, httpx

I am attempting to optimize a simple web scraper that I made. It gets a list of urls from a table on a main page and then goes to each of those "sub" urls and gets information from those pages. I was able to successfully write it synchronously and using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()`. However, I am trying to optimize it to use `asyncio` and `httpx` as these seem to be very fast for making hundreds of http requests.

I wrote the following script using `asyncio` and `httpx` however, I keep getting the following errors:

```
httpcore.RemoteProtocolError: Server disconnected without sending a response.

RuntimeError: The connection pool was closed while 4 HTTP requests/responses were still in-flight.
```

It appears that I keep losing connection when I run the script. I even attempted running a synchronous version of it and get the same error. I was thinking that the remote server was blocking my requests, however, **I am able to run my original program and go to each of the urls from the same IP address without issue**.

What would cause this exception and how do you fix it?

```
import httpx
import asyncio

async def get_response(client, url):
    resp = await client.get(url, headers=random_user_agent()) # Gets a random user agent.
    html = resp.text
    return html


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = []

        # Get list of urls to parse.
        urls = get_events('https://main-url-to-parse.com')
        
        # Get the responses for the detail page for each event
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_response(client, url)))
            
        detail_responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        for resp in detail_responses:
            event = get_details(resp) # Parse url and get desired info
        
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same issue. The problem occurs when there is an exception in one of the asyncio.gather tasks. When it's raised, it causes httpx.Client to call __ aexit __ and cancel all the current requests. You could bypass this by using return_exceptions=True as an argument for asyncio.gather.

```
async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = []

        # Get list of urls to parse.
        urls = get_events('https://main-url-to-parse.com')
    
       # Get the responses for the detail page for each event
       for url in urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_response(client, url)))
        
       detail_responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

       for resp in detail_responses:
         # here you would need to do smth with the exceptions 
         # if isinstance(resp, Exception): ...
         event = get_details(resp) # Parse url and get desired info
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do if even the `return_exceptions=True` arg doesn't work?

Comment: Well, I hardly imagine this situation, if you could provide more information it may help, anyway try/except is also a way out